# Plotting tf-idf matrix on a 2-dimensional space

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot, tf-idf

Good morning,
I have used a tf idf matrix to do a k-means clustering, in order to find the recurring topics in songs text.
In the end I got 4 clusters. I used the following code for plotting:

```
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE
from sklearn.decomposition import TruncatedSVD
k = 4
tfs_reduced = TruncatedSVD(n_components=k, random_state=7).fit_transform(tfidf_matrix)
tfs_embedded = TSNE(n_components=2).fit_transform(tfs_reduced)

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10, 10))
ax = plt.axes()
plt.scatter(tfs_embedded[:, 0], tfs_embedded[:, 1], c=labels)
plt.show()
```

The plotting seems to be correct but I can't add a legend where each of the colors used is assigned to a specific cluster.
How can i do?

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are two problems with your code.

1. First, you need to call scatter() once for each cluster you are plotting.  Since you didn't include all of the code necessary to reproduce your `tfs_embedded` variable, I don't know what that will involve in your case.  Presumably, however, you can subdivide that data into multiple calls to the scatter function.
2. The second problem is that you need to call scatter from the axes, instead of from the plot (i.e., ax.scatter instead of plt.scatter).

The example code below will show you how this can work.  The output plot is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNBem.png).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1,2,4,3,7,5]
y = [2.2,1.0,0.8,8.6,3.6,7.8]
C1 = 'red'
C2 = 'blue'
L1 = "Cluster 1"
L2 = "Cluster 2"
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10, 10))
ax = plt.axes()
ax.scatter(x[0:3], y[0:3], label=L1, c=C1, edgecolors='none')
ax.scatter(x[3:6], y[3:6], label=L2, c=C2, edgecolors='none')
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Actually, `scatter` can be called from `plt` in this case. the color parameter could then be a 1D array with the ith element being the color of the ith x point. Moreover, `legend` can be called form plot. I would argue that working off pyplot as opposed to the axes would be more pythonic in this case. Also, there is no need to set a `fig` object.

Comment: Good catch.  If that's the case, then the essential fix to OP's problem is to call scatter multiple times with different labels.  I think the OP doesn't want a different color for every point, but to group multiple points as "clusters" using one color per cluster, as in the linked example plot.

Comment: Also, when I called scatter from plt, the colors of the clusters were correct, but the legend entries all had the same color.  I think that's why calling from the axes seemed to be important.  But maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: After looking at the matplotlib docs, they use a loop to denote each class of points, so I suppose that's the intended method. `plt.scatter()` will need to be called for each of the clusters as you say. My original comment missed the need to have multi-class legend support!

Comment: I'd be interested to know if my answer worked for OP ChiaraA.